# Is it true that every Banach space has at least one extreme point that is normed by some point?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Definition: Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ be its continuous dual of $X,$ that is, $X^*$ contains all bounded linear functionals on $X.$ 
Denote 
$$B_{X^*} = \{x^*\in X^*: \|x^*\|_{X^*}\leq 1\}.$$
We say that $x^*\in B_{X^*}$ is an **extreme point of** $B_{X^*}$ if whenever 
$$x^* = \frac{1}{2}(y_1^*+y_2^*)$$
for some $y_1^*,y_2^*$ with $\|y_i^*\|_{X^*} \leq 1$ for all $i=1,2,$ we have $x^* = y_1^*=y_2^*.$

---

> **Question**: Given a Banach space $X.$
>   Is it true that there exists an extreme point $x^*$ of $B_{X^*}$ such that 
>   $$x^*(x) = 1$$ 
>   for some $x\in X$ with $\|x\|\leq 1?$

In other words, is it true that every Banach space has at least one extreme point that is normed by some point?

Comment: I do not like your wording.  I would say you defined **extreme point** not of $B_X$ but of $B_{X^*}$.  And then you ask a question about **extreme functional** not **extreme point**.  I think you should re-write the question.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have modified my question. Do you think it is okay now?

Comment: Yes, it looks good now.  And Robert Israel answered already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take any $x$ with $\|x\|=1$. $S(x) = \{x^* \in X^*: x^*(x) = \|x^*\| = 1 \}$ is a nonempty (by Hahn-Banach) weak-* compact convex set, so by Krein-Milman it has extreme points.  Any extreme point of $S(x)$ is an extreme point of $B_{X^*}$.

Comment: Seriously, how can I forgot Krein-Milman theorem....